# Auto-save and auto-create new worksheet based on date

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that contains a worksheet showing monthly figures.

When my workbook is opened, VBA code should check the current date and save and create a new "blank" copy of that specific monthly worksheet, preserving everything in that sheet (formulas, formatting, cell size and width, etc.) EXCEPT for the sales figures entered for that month. Essentially giving me a fresh template to enter new sales data.

When I open the workbook, if it detects that the date is the first of the month, it should save the current monthly worksheet, labeling it as the prior month (because technically it would be filled with data from the previous month), then after it saves, it should create a new template from that previous worksheet and insert the new fresh template into the workbook, deleting the old one.

Both macros work when run manually. One saves the worksheet and the other creates a new worksheet. I have no idea how to make it so that both macros check the current date before doing anything else and then, ONLY if the date is returned as the first of the month, should the macros continue.

This is the code, separated into two macros so some of the code is different.

```vb
Sub WorksheetExport()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsToSave As Worksheet
    Dim filePathToSave As String
    Dim strName As String
    Dim bCheck As Boolean
    Dim wsMaster As Worksheet
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    strName = Format(Date, "_mmyyyy")
    Set wsMaster = Worksheets("bqtest")
    
    filePathToSave = "C:\Users\thelo\Desktop\Quail Stuff\TEST\"
    
    Set wsToSave = Worksheets("bqtest")
    
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
      Filename:=filePathToSave & wsToSave.Name & strName & ".pdf"

End Sub
```

---

```vb
Sub CreateNewSheetWithMonth()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsM As Worksheet
    Dim strName As String
    Dim bCheck As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsM = Sheets("bqtest")
    strName = Format(Date, "_mmyyyy")
    bCheck = Len(Sheets("bqtest" & strName).Name) > 0

    If bCheck = False Then
        wsM.Copy After:=Sheets(1)
        ActiveSheet.Name = "bqtest" & strName
    End If

    Set wsM = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: If you want your code to run automatically on opening the workbook, place it in the Workbook_Open event handler.
Since you write that your two macros work manually, call them from within Workbook_Open.

Comment: I suggest not to check if the date is the first of the month. The first of the month may not be a working day. Continue using your approach checking if there is a worksheet matching the current month. If it doesn't, it's a new month. So keep using `If bCheck = False Then ... End If`. Put your actions in between.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim latestSheetName As String, monthstr As String
    Dim currentMonth As Integer, currentYear As Integer, latestYear As Integer, latestMonth As Integer, lMonth As Integer, lYear As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    
    ' Get the current year and month
    currentMonth = Format(Date, "mm")
    currentYear = Format(Date, "yyyy")
    
    If Len(CStr(currentMonth)) < 2 Then
        monthstr = "0" & currentMonth
    Else
        monthstr = currentMonth
    End If
    
    ' Loop through all sheets and find the latest one
    lMonth = 0
    lYear = 0
    For Each sheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If sheet.Name Like "bqtest_######" Then
            latestYear = Right(sheet.Name, 4)
            latestMonth = Mid(sheet.Name, 8, 2)
            If latestMonth > lMonth Or latestYear > lYear Then
                latestSheetName = sheet.Name
                lYear = latestYear
                lMonth = latestMonth
            End If
        End If
    Next sheet
    
    ' Check if the latest sheet is older than the current year and month
    If currentYear = lYear Or currentMonth > lMonth Then
        Worksheets(latestSheetName).Copy After:=Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
            ActiveSheet.Name = "bqtest_" & monthstr & currentYear
            lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            'clear range starting at A2 to last row change accordingly
            ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Resize(lastRow - 1).ClearContents
    ElseIf currentYear > lYear Then
        Worksheets(latestSheetName).Copy After:=Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
           ActiveSheet.Name = "bqtest_" & monthstr & currentYear
            lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            'clear range starting at A2 to last row change accordingly
            ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Resize(lastRow - 1).ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Ran this code and received the error "Subscript out of range" on the line "Worksheets(latestSheetName).Copy After:=Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)"

Comment: You should modify the comparison. Change `And` to `Or` in `If latestMonth > lMonth And latestYear > lYear Then`. Otherwise `latestSheetName` is assigned a value only when the year and the month have changed. Further down write the same instead of `If currentYear = lYear And currentMonth > lMonth Then`.

Comment: Had a bit to do yesterday so I didn't have a chance to do more with the code until now, but modifying the comparisons as you suggested did not solve the issue.. I am still getting the same error on the same line as before.

Comment: Some hints for debugging:
1. Insert `MsgBox latestSheetName` before the line that throws the error. Save and close the file. Open it again and see what `latestSheetName` contains.
2. Insert `Stop` before `currentMonth = Format(Date, "mm")`
Save and close the file. (You can't set a breakpoint because the code runs immediately when you open the file. That's why you type `Stop``). When you open the file, the code stops at `Stop`. Press F8 to go through your code line by line. Put the cursor on a variable and press Shft-F9 to see it's value.

Comment: 3. Search the web for more tips how to debug VBA. I'm sure you will find the bug.

Comment: Tried that. The messsage box that appears just shows up blank. When I hover my cursor over "latestSheetName", it tells me latestSheetName="" .... sheet.Name also says "Object variable or with block variable not set" when I hover my cursor over that as well... I'm really stuck at how to fix this. Like I said, I don't really know much about the vba stuff but I didn't expect a simple task to turn into a four-day long headache :(

Comment: I apologize, I haven't had a closer look at the code and I've messed it up. I will post a new solution based on your original code.

Comment: @Dzewa can you provide a screenshot of your sheet names in the workbook? i have tested my code and it works without an error

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CreateNewSheetWithMonth()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strToday As String
    Dim bCheck As Boolean
    Const strTARGET_PATH = "C:\Users\thelo\Desktop\Quail Stuff\TEST\"

    'activate the worksheet bqtest... (the workbook may contain other sheets, too)
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'check each worksheet
        If InStr(ws.Name, "bqtest") = 1 Then 'if sheet name starts with "bqtest"
            ws.Activate         'activate it
        End If
    Next ws

    'check if a worksheet exists for this month
    strToday = Format(Date, "_mmyyyy") 'format today's date
    On Error Resume Next        'avoid error if not existing
    bCheck = Len(Sheets("bqtest" & strToday).Name) > 0  'check if exists
    On Error GoTo 0             'restore error checking
    
    'take action if new month
    If bCheck = False Then      'skip if worksheet exists
        'save last month's worksheet as PDF
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
          Filename:=strTARGET_PATH & ActiveSheet.Name & ".pdf"
        
        'copy ActiveSheet and paste it after ActiveSheet, activate it
        ActiveSheet.Copy After:=ActiveSheet
        ActiveSheet.Name = "bqtest" & strToday 'rename to this month
    End If

End Sub
```

This is basically your code with some unnecessary code removed.

I have changed it so that it exports the last month's worksheet under its name, e.g. `bqtest_032003.pdf` for March 2023.

In your code there is no deletion of the old month's worksheet. If you want VBA to do it automatically, delete the line `ActiveSheet.Copy After:=ActiveSheet`. Then the old worksheet gets renamed to the new month instead of copied.

You mention that you want the sales figures to be deleted in the new month. Either you do it manually or you have to write your own code since I don't know where these figures are written to.

I hope this time it works.